# Realm decryption failed on devices but works on Simulator

Tags: swift, encryption, realm

My App uses an encrypted Realm that opens on app launch in the AppDelegate. Before integrating Encryption, the App runs perfectly fine as my expectation. However, once the encryption is involved, it only works with the simulator but not a real device. the error message:

> Failed to open Realm file at path '/var/mobile/.../Documents/default.realm': Realm file decryption failed (Decryption failed)

I've tried to download the source code from Realm but found nothing. I also created my own key but this changes nothing:

```
var key = Data(count: 64)
    _ = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (pointer: UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) in
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, pointer.baseAddress!) }
```

I feel like I miss something from the info.plist but I couldn't find a trace.

```
static var getkey: Getkey = Getkey() // the key is from MondoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/realm-files/encrypt-a-realm/

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    ...
    initRealm()        
    return true
}

func initRealm(){        
    // Configure for an encrypted realm
    var config = Realm.Configuration(
        encryptionKey: AppDelegate.getkey.getKey(),
        schemaVersion: self.version,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
          if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {}
        }
    )
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

and in my ViewModel, I have this setup

```
    init() {
    setupObserver()
}

private func setupObserver(){
    let config = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: AddressViewModel.getkey.getKey())
    do{
        let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
        let results = realm.objects(Address.self)
        ...
    }catch{
        print("setup addy ---> \(config)")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is a bit confusing; the `initRealm` uses one key and then the `setupObserver` uses a different key? I would suggest following the code in the [Encryption Example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/realm-files/encrypt-a-realm/#example) as that works.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Realm upgraded from an old version (unencrypted version)?

If so, you need to manually update your realm file to an encrypted file.

Comment: I even created a new project with the newest realm version but not working still

Comment: Try to use realm directly in your viewModel, like `let realm = try Realm()`